# How make a drop down work without having the content below shifting down on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three drop downs that currently work as an accordion so when I click on a drop down, the rest of the content below shits down, which I dont want.

How can I make the content after each drop down not move whenever I click on a dropdown?

I tried using absolute positioning but it just messed up with the content.

My html looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var dropOneValue = "";
  $("ul.which-way").on("click", function() {
  $(this).find('li').toggleClass("open-list");
  $(this).find('open-list').css("display", "block");
  });
  $("li.cadja").on("click", function(){
   console.log($(this).find('.value').html());
      dropOneValue = $(this).find('.value').html();
       $($(this).parent().find('.which-init')[0]).html($(this).html());
  });  

  $('a#trip').on("click", function(){
   $(this).attr("href", "https://www.westcoastway.co.za/"+dropOneValue);
  });
  
  $('a#tour').on("click", function(){
   $(this).attr("href", "http://capeytours.co.za/west-coast-tours/"+dropOneValue);
  });
});
```

```css
.which-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

ul.which-way li:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
.value{
display: none !important;
}

ul.which-way {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
 border-radius: 2.5px;
}

ul.which-way:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ec008c;
}

li.which-init:after {
    content: '\f002';
    font-family: fontawesome;
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #555;
}
.value{
 display: none;
}
li.open-list {
  display: block !important;
}

.find{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

a.find{
  display: block;
    background: #ec008c;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 2.5px;
    animation-duration: .1ms;
    -webkit-animation-name: mui-node-inserted;
    animation-name: mui-node-inserted;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.15;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}


a.find:hover{
 /*background-color: #F15A24 !important;
    border-top: 1.5px solid #F15A24;
    color: white;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;*/
}


.way-widget{
 float: none !important;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.bold{
 font-weight: bold;
}

.pink{
 color: #ec008c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="which-wrapper">
  <label class="bold">Would you like to explore the West Coast?</label>
  <div class="drowpdown-one dropdown">
    <ul class="which-way">
      <li class="which-init"><span class="pink">Unguided</span> <span class="bold">I-Day Return Trips</span></li>
      <li data-value="value 2" class="cadja"><span class="value">darling-wine-hops-day-by-which-way</span><span class="real">Darling Wine & Beer Trip</span></li>
      <li data-value="value 3" class="cadja"><span class="value">mamre-werf-khwa-ttu-culture-day-by-which-way-trips</span><span class="real">Culture & Adventure Trip</span></li>
      <li data-value="value 4" class="cadja"><span class="value">cape-west-coast-wildlife-fossil-trip</span><span class="real">Wildlife & Fossils Trip</span></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" target="__blank" id="trip" class="find">FIND YOUR TRIP</a>
  </div>
  <div class="drowpdown-two dropdown">
    <ul class="which-way">
      <li class="which-init"><span class="pink">Guided</span> <span class="bold">Multi-Day Tours</span></li>
      <li data-value="value 2" class="cadja"><span class="value">5-day-west-coast</span><span class="real">5 Day West Coast Explorer</span></li>
      <li data-value="value 3" class="cadja"><span class="value">5-day-namaqua-spring-flower-tour</span><span class="real">5 Day Namaqualand Spring Flower</span></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" target="__blank" id="tour" class="find">FIND YOUR TRIP</a>
  </div>
  <div class="drowpdown-three dropdown">
    <ul class="which-way">
      <li class="which-init"><span class="pink">Guided</span> <span class="bold">Tours departing Langebaan</span></li>
      <li data-value="value 2" class="cadja"><span class="value">flower-routes</span><span class="real">Eco Tourism Routes West Coast</span></li>
      <li data-value="value 3" class="cadja"><span class="value">coastal-tour</span><span class="real">Coastal Tours</span></li>
      <li data-value="value 3" class="cadja"><span class="value">adventure-trips</span><span class="real">Adventure Tours</span></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" target="__blank" id="tour-2" class="find">FIND YOUR TRIP</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope you can help and [check my pen if needed](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/KmvdYq?editors=1111).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your css for this:
Your drop downs must have their paddings removed and you can give them with of 100% instead 96%.

```
.which-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
.drowpdown-one{
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
ul.which-way {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 2.5px;
    top: -32px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: white;
}

ul.which-way li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}

.value{
    display: none;
}

li.open-list {
    display: block !important;
}

.find{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

a.find{
    display: block;
    background: #ec008c;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 2.5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #cb348d;
    animation-duration: .1ms;
    -webkit-animation-name: mui-node-inserted;
    animation-name: mui-node-inserted;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-top: 1.5px solid #e542a3;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.15;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}


a.find:hover{
    background-color: #cb348d;
    border-top: 1.5px solid #cb348d;
    color: white;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;*/
}

ul.which-way:hover {
    border: 1px solid #ec008c;
}

li.which-init:after {
    content: '\f002';
    font-family: fontawesome;
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #555;
}

.way-widget{
    float: none !important;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.way-widget p {
    float: none !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.bold{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.pink{
    color: #ec008c;
}

.indexed{
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

Add this css

```
.drowpdown-one{
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
ul.which-way {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwEPeP?editors=1111

Comment: I added this to my pen and for some reason it does not work.
http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/KmvdYq?editors=1111

Comment: I actually managed to make it work but I see that the drop downs with goes wider than its content with. How exactly can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Make this changes in your Pen "[codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/KmvdYq?editors=1111](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/KmvdYq?editors=1111) "

```
ul.which-way {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 2.5px;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.cadja{
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following css in your style.

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}
ul.which-way{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
a.find{
  margin-top:40px;
  display:inline-block
}
```